# Categorized style won't display in QGIS2.2

Tags: style, qgis-2.2

I'm a qgis novice trying to put together a building characteristics map. While 44 out of 46 of my layers have their data categorized and displayed correctly, two layers will not display different colours. Instead I am getting the same colour all over my map, which is the colour assigned to an extra unvalued category that appears at the bottom of my list, as shown in the screenshot.

[image: Styles]

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you coloured on a single column, or used a function for it?

Comment: I have coloured on a single column.

Comment: I managed to get my maps together by ignoring the faulty columns and copying their data to new ones with different names. 
I wouldn't call it "solved", but at least I have my data appearing now.

Comment: I stumbled upon the `Use / |v|` in your picture. Maybe you had reserved words for column names. I usually put them in double quotes.

Comment: That was my guess too, so I used more casual names. I have no idea how to reserve words for column names, but I will look into it. 

Thanks for taking the time to reply :]

Comment: The names are reserved by the programming languages used. You have little influence on that :-)